# The correct way to monitor property change in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I searched some code in the Internet that listen to specific property being changed on a `INotifyPropertyChanged` object. Most of them are in the form

```
notifier.PropertyChanged +=
    (s,e) => {
        if(e.PropertyName.Equals(propertyName))
            run_my_code();
    }
```

However, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Shall the above implementation be

```
notifier.PropertyChanged +=
    (s,e) => {
        if(e.PropertyName.Equals(propertyName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName))
            run_my_code();
    }
```

? As there are so many code did it another way, would it means I have to assume something else? I sometimes have some code that does not work when I notify property change with null or empty strings.

Comment: The documentation is saying that those implementing and raising the event could possibly use a null or empty but it is implementation specific. Therefore... it depends. My thoughts are use your first approach unless the second approach is required.

Comment: You are correct

Comment: The documentation has no control over the way my code abuses Microsoft's interface, so you have to be permissive. N.B. my iPhone offers to autocorrect "Microsoft" to "microaggression"; make of that what you will. But a nod, you know, blind horse, good boys... all that.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what `run_my_code` is going to do. The `PropertyChanged` event simply indicates that one or more properties have changed on the object.

If `run_my_code` needs to make decisions based on which property has changed, then you'll want to check. If it doesn't, then you don't need to check.

Comment: The code I quoted is *actually* did the check: if the changed property is not in its interest, it does nothing. My question is: if there is no changed property name, according to Microsoft this says all properties may change. So shall I `run_my_code`?

Comment: @EarthEngine Whatever happened to the object to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event is entirely under the control of the implementer. _Even if they pass a property name back to you_, there's no rule which says anything actually changed. There's no definitive answer to that question unless we know the implementation.